# Error connecting to SQL Server from Python using pyodbc on CentOS 8

Tags: python, sql-server, odbc, pyodbc

I am having trouble connecting to SQL Server from a Python environment using pyodbc on a CentOS 8 system.

**Environment:**

- CentOS 8
- Python version: 3.11.2
- pyodbc version: 4.0.39
- ODBC Driver: ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server

**Error:**

```
('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.10.so.4.1' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

**Steps I've taken:**

- Verified that the ODBC driver is installed and listed correctly.
- Successfully connected to SQL Server using `isql` with the same connection string.
- Verified the driver path and ensured the library exists in the mentioned directory.
- Checked dependencies using `ldd`.
- Reinstalled SQL Server ODBC driver, unixODBC, and pyodbc.
- Checked environment variables and ensured LD_LIBRARY_PATH was set correctly.
- Set SELinux to permissive mode for testing, but it didn't help.

The issue persists only when trying to connect from a Python environment. The driver works perfectly from the command line.

I'm stumped and would appreciate any help or guidance on this issue. Has anyone faced something similar or have any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Are you using a Python virtual environment like Anaconda?

Comment: Yes, I use venv, but this error persists in the base environment. @GordThompson

Comment: The error message may not be about `libmsodbcsql-17.10.so.4.1` itself. i.e.: When in your venv does `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` include `/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64` as well as all of the directories for all of the dependencies you enumerated from `ldd`?